# Can a user edit the page source, manipulate hidden field values and then post the form with those values?

Tags: html

On various sites, you often see in the page source some hidden values on forms (usually holding some kind of constant, key, ID, etc). Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_submit_check" value="1">
```

I'd assume this website is double checking the form was posted by checking _submit_checks value for 1. Would it be possible to edit the source and change that to 0, then post the data and thus make the form fail to post server side?

This example isn't very dangerous to the server as it will simply ignore the request but are there any possible security risks with using hidden fields (other than the obvious: they can still read the value in the source, I'm more worried about if they can edit it).

Comment: In short, yes. This is exactly why you should always validate user input.

Comment: ... on the server side (finishing @MikeB's comment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes a user could copy your html form, change the values and then post to your server.  This is why it is important to always validate and sanitize user input including hidden input values on the server side and not just the client side(ie javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Several people gave answers but it looks like you were first.

Comment: Can you please explain me how user can change the value of hidden field manually using F12 and submit the form using the modified value. I tried changing the value but while clicking the button the value again changes to default.

Comment: Without seeing your specific form it is hard to say. There is a chance that the form you were trying to alter has a script to check the values before submit and correct the hidden fields. If you need a more detailed answer please submit your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can edit it, and nowdays when browsers like Chrome and Firefox have integrated web development tools is easier to modify values. That's why **you shouldn't trust on data received from user**.

Comment: I knew never to trust input from a user, I was just wondering if you could ignore hidden fields but it seems nothing is safe!

Comment: Can you please explain me how user can change the value of hidden field manually using F12 and submit the form using the modified value. I tried changing the value but while clicking the button the value again changes to default.

Comment: If not, then an user can download the page, edit it with a text editor, open it in the browser (the modified page) and send the form. O manipulate network request at the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If you are using Firebug/IE Developer Tools/etc, you can edit anything on the page and submit the form with that data. You can also run any js and make edits that way. This is one of the main reasons you really really need to validate all inputs on the server side before doing anything with them.

Comment: Can you please explain me how user can change the value of hidden field manually using F12 and submit the form using the modified value. I tried changing the value but while clicking the button the value again changes to default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.  Using modern browsers with developer/debugging tools built in or as extensions, they don't even need to save the form to edit it.   This is why you should never trust any data as a form submission and always validate and sanitize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very easy using developer tools that plugin to browsers. Such tools are used to trick people and lie also i.e. someone creating a landing page for a dodgy get rich scheme might edit the numbers on their Paypal account then take a screenshot. This is meant to prove they are rich.

Some of us know better. We know everything needs to be confirmed/validated in the world of internet and accept nothing at face value.

I'm currently looking at preventing form hacking in Wordpress and speeding development up by storing the information about a form in the database. This is done on the fly. All forms are built using many functions, I do not code HTML. Every visible has a validation method which is stored in the database. During processing the method is queried and applied.

In short a user could edit hidden inputs all they like. The database holds a copy of everything temporarily and the processes uses that.